# CUPS-PDF not outputting

Tags: raspbian, pdf, cups

I have set up a CUPS print server on Raspbian that prints to cups-pdf. I can print to the pdf printer without any trouble from the CUPS settings page. I am not receiving files when I print from Windows. I have set up samba according to [this](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-print-server/) tutorial. When setting up on the Windows side, the printer was recognized when I selected the `HP Color LaserJet 2700 Series PCL6` driver.

I do not receive any errors whenever I print something from Windows, but the file does not show up where it should. The default location is `/var/spool/cups-pdf/ANONYMOUS/`. The only thing that shows up there is `cups-pdf_log.pdf`. `~/PDF/` only contains the test print sent from the settings page.

Because all of the logs read that each file sent from Windows worked, I'm thinking that either it didn't work and the logs are all incorrect (unlikely) or the files are going to another directory that I don't know about. Any ideas what might be going on, or are the details too vague?

Answer (score 0):

Through some coincidences, I found that the file isn't being written correctly, I can't do much to change the name, and the file is being over-written because of the naming issues. So, the file `cups-pdf_log.pdf` is the output file.